# How to use DATE format in sql - Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following result set.

```
purchase_date              invoice_no
2020-05-06 13:14:54.000000 I2516211
2020-05-05 20:30:08.000000 I2515992
2020-05-05 02:00:26.000000 I2515763
2020-05-03 22:00:51.000000 I2515504
```

I need to get the result set as follows.(showing how many invoices per day count)

```
2020-05-03  1
2020-05-06  1
2020-05-05  2
```

not sure how to use the date format function in the sql.(Im using teradata)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the value to a string using `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), count(*)
from t
group by to_char(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
order by to_char(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

You can also convert the value to a date:

```
select cast(purchase_date as date), count(*)
from t
group by cast(purchase_date as date)
order by cast(purchase_date as date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as Gordon's answer but with re-use of column aliases (Teradata feature):

```sql
SELECT 
  CAST(purchase_date AS DATE) AS purchase_date, 
  COUNT(*) AS purchase_count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY purchase_date
ORDER BY purchase_date;
```